# Validation of fields on multipart/form submission in Loopack 4

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a form submitting multipart/form content to my Loopback 4 api. I've followed the [File Transfer Example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/examples/file-transfer), which is working fine, but I need to validate the fields that come through in the request body against the definition set up in the model. Looking at the [rest package documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.rest.html#rest-package), I see "validateValueAgainstSchema" as an option, and it looks like it should be exactly what I need. However, when I try to add it to the rest package imports, it is not found. I can import the "validateRequestBody" function, but since I'm parsing the request already, I don't have the requestBody, so that method does not appear to work for me (judging by the errors I've gotten when trying to use it: "Request body is required at Object.validateRequestBody"). Is there a way to make the validateRequestBody function work? Or to use the validateValueAgainstSchema function?

My code:

```
import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
import {repository} from '@loopback/repository';
import {get, HttpErrors, param, post, Request, requestBody, Response, RestBindings, validateRequestBody} from '@loopback/rest';
import {FILE_UPLOAD_SERVICE} from '../keys';
import {Application} from '../models';
import {ApplicationDetailsRepository, ApplicationMasterRepository} from '../repositories';
import {JWTService, JWTServiceBindings} from '../services/jwt-service';
import {PdfGeneratorService} from '../services/pdf-generator.service';
import {FileUploadHandler} from '../types';
export class ApplicationController {
  constructor(
    @repository(ApplicationMasterRepository)
    public applicationMasterRepository: ApplicationMasterRepository,
    @repository(ApplicationDetailsRepository)
    public applicationDetailsRepository: ApplicationDetailsRepository,
    @inject(JWTServiceBindings.SERVICE)
    public jwtService: JWTService,
    @inject('services.PdfGeneratorService')
    public pdfGenerator: PdfGeneratorService,
    @inject(FILE_UPLOAD_SERVICE) private handler: FileUploadHandler,
  ) {}

  @post('/application', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Application creation',
      },
    },
  })
  @authenticate('jwt')
  async create(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'multipart/form-data': {
          'x-parser': 'stream',
          schema: {type: 'object'},
        },
      },
    })
    request: Request,
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) response: Response,
  ): Promise<any> {
    // Get the files and fields from the request
    const filesAndFields = await new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.handler(request, response, (err: unknown) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        } else {
          resolve(ApplicationController.getFilesAndFields(request));
        }
      });
    })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('catch err', err);
        throw new Error('Error handling the submission' + err);
      });

    const files = filesAndFields.files;
    const signature = files.find((file: any) => file.fieldname === 'signature');

    if (signature === undefined) {
      throw new HttpErrors.UnprocessableEntity('A signature file is required');
    }

    let body = filesAndFields.fields;

    try {
      let validation = await validateRequestBody(body, {
        description: 'Application submission',
        required: true,
        content: {
          'multipart/form': {...Application}
        }
      });
      console.log(validation);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw new Error(err);
    }

    console.log('body', body);
    return false;

  }

  private static getFilesAndFields(request: Request) {
    const uploadedFiles = request.files;
    const mapper = (f: globalThis.Express.Multer.File) => ({
      fieldname: f.fieldname,
      originalname: f.originalname,
      encoding: f.encoding,
      mimetype: f.mimetype,
      size: f.size,
    });
    let files: any = [];
    if (Array.isArray(uploadedFiles)) {
      files = uploadedFiles.map(mapper);
    } else {
      for (const filename in uploadedFiles) {
        files.push(...uploadedFiles[filename].map(mapper));
      }
    }
    return {files, fields: request.body};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main key was to update so that my @loopback/rest was at at least version 5.2.0. I also needed to do a bit more conversion, importing jsonToSchemaObject from @loopback/openapi-v3, but the main crux is this:

```
await validateValueAgainstSchema(body, jsonToSchemaObject(getJsonSchema(Application)));
```

Many thanks to the Loopback Slack group for helping me find this. :)